# Stripe payments with Klarna source

Tags: stripe-payments, klarna

We use Stripe with Klarna as source. This works just fine on development, but I production the source creation fails with:

> This payment method (klarna) is not activated for your account. You can only create testmode klarna payment methods.

Well if I go to our dashboard > settings > payments, I see that Klarna (Beta) is active for our account.

I talked to 2 different support people, they can‘t help and forwarded it to someone who can and I haven‘t heard anything.

Anyone having an idea?

Comment: Since this is a configuration issue with your Stripe account, you're really only going to be able to get a straight answer from Stripe Support directly. Sorry!

Comment: Yeah I figured that, I was hoping someone else had the same issue and would share their experience.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is an account thing. Nothing to workaround in code.